# Cannot connect to RabbitMQ Server from another containerised .Net core RabbitMQ client

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have been able to set up containerised RabbitMQ server, and reach into it with basic .NET Core clients and check message send and receive working using management portal on http://localhost:15672/.

But I am having real frustrations when I also Containerise my Sender/Receiver .NET Core clients, on being able to establish a connection. I have set up an explicit "shipnetwork", so all containers in the following docker-compose deployment should see each other.

[image: Docker Compose]

This is the Error I get in the sender attempting the connection:

[image]

My SendRabbit .NET core App is as follows. This code was working on my local Windows 10 development machine, with a host of 'localhost' against the RabbitMQ server running as a container. But when I change this to a [linux] docker project, and set the host to "rabbitmq", to correspond to the service name in the docker compose. Now I just get Endpoint Connection errors exceptions within my Sender container.

[image]

I have also attempted the same RabbitMQ server and Sender Image with the same docker-compose on a Google Cloud Linux Virtual Machine, and get the same errors. So I do not think it is the Windows 10 docker hosting VM environment hassles.

I thought docker was going to make development and deployment of microservices, but setting up a basic RabbitMQ connections is proving to be a real pain.

I have thought that maybe the rabbitmq server is not up and running, so perhaps ambitious to put in the same docker-compose. But I have checked running my SendRabbit container
$docker run --network shipnetwork sendrabbit
some minutes later. But I still get the same connection error

Answer (score 0):

docker networks **** networks !

When I checked the actual docker networks, I had:

bridge
host
shipnetwork
rabbitship_shipnetwork

The docker compose was actually creating the 'new' network: rabbitship_shipnetwork  every time it was spun up, and placing the rabbimq server on that network. The netwrok is named from appending the directory name, with the name in the compsos yaml.  So I was using the wrong network in my senders. So I should have been using

$docker run --network rabbitship_shipnetwork sendrabbit

This works fine, and creates messages into the rabbitmq server

So I don't feel that docker-compose is actually very helpful in creating networks, since it is sensitive to the directory name it is run in !  Its unlikely that I can build an app .docker files, and deploy all Apps from a single directory, especially when rabbitmq has to be started separately, before senders and receivers can use it.

docker-compose 0

Comment: `docker-compose` networking works just fine - the network it creates is prefixed with project name (directory name by default) to avoid name collision with any preexisting network. If you wanted to connect to a preexisting network, you should have marked your network as external in `docker-compose.yml`. Read the docs more carefully next time: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network